# TestCase "test_Dialog_focusDestroy" does not work properly in Dojo release 1.5

Tags: dojo

I'm currently using dojo 1.5 and trying to create a simple dojo dialog where once focus is on dialog the main content cannot be edited. I found this functionality under following testcase.

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit/tests/test_Dialog_focusDestroy.html

Unfortunately, This test case **only** work for **first click** of the "show dialog" button (once click, can not edit main content). Subsequent clicks of "show dialog" button does not disable the main content as intended:( (without refreshing the page). Since overlay functionality does not work properly, user is able to create multiple instances of same dialog by clicking "show dialog" button.

However, I found this test case properly work in one of Dojo previous release 1.2.3.

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.2.3/dojo-release-1.2.3/dijit/tests/test_Dialog_focusDestroy.html

Please provide me a clarification regarding above dialog functionality. Is there any way to get around this problem in Dojo 1.5?

**[EDIT]**
I resolve this problem by calling .hide() before calling .destroy() of dialog. Refer to description of
   http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5351. It looks like this bug should be re-open.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a bug, but perhaps not the same as but #5351.  The area behind the dialog is not disabled, but the keys and focus seem to be working correctly.  Perhaps you should open a new ticket.